# why sometimes you need to have a dummy object for event storage (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I don't understand why sometimes you need to have a dummy object in JavaScript to store events, like following code:

```
Metal.Gold = function() {
   var temp = $("<div>"); //dummy object
   this.Submit = function(url1, method, data){
      temp.trigger("Submit", data); //invoke trigger for dummy object??
      $.ajax({
         url:url1,
         data:JSON.stringify(data),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType:"json",
         success: function(data){
            temp.trigger("SubmittSuccess", data); //????
            //doSomething
         },
         error: function(error){
           temp.trigger("SubmitFailure", error);// ???
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Why a dummy element has been declared and its trigger has been invoked three times?

**Updated**

Here it invokes Submit method:

```
myGold.Submit(....
function(data){
   temp.trigger("SubmitQuantitySuccess", data);
}, ....

this.OnSubmitQuantitySuccess = function (handler) {temp.on("SubmitQuantitySuccess", handler); }
```

I have search all files I cannot find any method with name `SubmitQuantitySuccess`. I don't know where and what happened with the data or error when it comes back.

Comment: Because they want to send events around, but they don't want to do it on global scope (i.e., on the document). Also, the three times is because of different events and different data being sent.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really the best way to do it. I've never seen anything like that but I guess it would work...

You probably want to return the `$.ajax` call in the Submit function, which will return a jqXHR object (a deferred object).

```
Metal.Gold = function() {
    this.Submit = function(url1, method, data){
        return $.ajax({
            url:url1,
            data:JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json"
        });
    }
}
```

So then you can do:

```
var myGold = new Metal.Gold();

myGold.Submit(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    .done(function () { ... })
    .fail(function () { ... });
```

More information on jQuery's deferred object [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

And jQuery's jqXHR object [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR)